# Running spring boot application jar by -cp instead of -jar

Tags: java, spring-boot

I can run my spring boot application JAR by:

```
java -Xms256M -Xmx1024M -Dspring.profiles.active=local -Dport=9999 -jar "\Path\To\sampleV1.0.jar"
```

But, when I try to run through `-cp`(reason being, I don't want to mention jar name since it will keep changing depending on new version and `-jar` doesn't support wildcards) option like:

```
java -Xms256M -Xmx1024M -Dspring.profiles.active=local -Dport=9999 -cp "\Path\to\jar\*" package.structure.name.MainClass
```

Then I am getting error:

```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication
>         at com.citi.isg.lmc.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:20)
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>         at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>         ... 1 more
```

The class code is :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class MainClass{


    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        System.setProperty("spring.config.name", "any_word_for_example");
        SpringApplication.run(MainClass.class, args);
    }
}
```

Please let me know if I did something wrong.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to circumvent a deploy problem that doesn't exist yet.  Do you really have no way of getting the absolute latest JAR before you execute it?

Comment: Actually, some automation software will create new JAR after each version and put it to same location with suffix of new version and back up old jar. It only starts application again through batch scripts where this java command is written.
So, it won't be a good way to change batch script for just jar name every time we have new version. Thanks.

Comment: What I'm saying is, you can solve this problem through the scripts themselves.  Even if you don't delete the previous version, you can still reference the newest version and only use that instead.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I agree, I did think of that too. I don't have control to that process. It has to be done that way only - keeping just one jar in targetLib directory.. :( Any idea why -cp does not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why your command doesn't work?

I see it's a spring boot application, and the main class of spring boot application is not your main class. See [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/executable-jar.html)

> How to launch without specifying the jar name?

Unzip your jar and check the MANIFEST file in META-INF, replace the main class in your command line by the main class mentioned here(for example the main class can be `org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher`).

Anyway, I have never tried this, and I don't think it's the right thing to do. Changing the script to get the right name is a better way, or maybe you could generate the jar with a fixed final name each time.

Comment: It worked :) Actually in MANIFEST.MF file, main class was
Main-Class: org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
And the class with which I was starting was declared under "Start-Class" property. Looks like, when I was running through -jar option, then also it looked for "JarLauncher" and then it picked my "MainClass" accordingly.  Thanks Buddy.